# Getting data from XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am struggling with reading XML file using PHP.

The XML I want to use is here:
http://www.gdacs.org/xml/rss.xml

Now, the data I am interested are the "item" nodes.

I created the following function, which gets the data:

```
$rawData = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);

foreach($rawData->channel->item as $value) { 
    $title = $value->title;
```

....
this works fine.

The nodes with the "gdcs:xxxx" were slightly more problematic, but I used the following code, which also works:

```
$subject = $value->children('dc', true)->subject;
```

Now the problem I have is with the "resources" node,

Basically the stripped down version of it would look like this:

```
<channel>
   <item>
      <gdacs:resources>
         <gdacs:resource id="xx" version="0" source="xx" url="xx" type="xx">
            <gdacs:title>xxx</gdacs:title>
         </gdacs:resource>
         <gdacs:resource id="xx" version="0" source="xx" url="xx" type="xx">
            <gdacs:title>xxx</gdacs:title>
         </gdacs:resource>
         <gdacs:resource id="xx" version="0" source="xx" url="xx" type="xx">
            <gdacs:title>xxx</gdacs:title>
         </gdacs:resource>
      </gdacs:resources>
   </item>
</channel>
```

How in this case would I get the resources? I was able to get always just the first resource and only the title of it. What I would like to do is get all the resources items, which have "type" of a particular value and get their URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the node occurrence of xpath with square brackets `[]` to align urls with corresponding `titles`. A more involved modification of @Daniel Batkilin's answer, you can incorporate both data pieces in an associative multidimensional array, requiring nested `for` loops.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.gdacs.org/xml/rss.xml'); 
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gdacs', 'http://www.gdacs.org');

$items = $xml->xpath("//channel/item");

$i = 1;
$out = array();
foreach($items as $x) {       

    $titles = $xml->xpath("//channel/item[".$i."]/gdacs:resources/gdacs:resource[@type='image']/gdacs:title");
    $urls = $xml->xpath("//channel/item[".$i."]/gdacs:resources/gdacs:resource[@type='image']/@url");

    for($j=0; $j<count($urls); $j++) {

        $out[$j.$i]['title'] = (string)$titles[$j];
        $out[$j.$i]['url'] = (string)$urls[$j];                    

    }

    $i++;
}

$out = array_values($out);
var_dump($out);
```

**ARRAY DUMP**

```
array(40) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(21) "Storm surge animation"
    ["url"]=>
    string(92) "http://webcritech.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ModellingCyclone/cyclonesurgeVM/1000226/final/outres1.gif"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(26) "Storm surge maximum height"
    ["url"]=>
    string(101) "http://webcritech.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ModellingCyclone/cyclonesurgeVM/1000226/final/P1_MAXHEIGHT_END.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(12) "Overview map"
    ["url"]=>
    string(64) "http://dma.gdacs.org/saved/gdacs/tc/1000226/clouds_1000226_2.png"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(41) "Map of rainfall accummulation in past 24h"
    ["url"]=>
    string(70) "http://dma.gdacs.org/saved/gdacs/tc/1000226/current_rain_1000226_2.png"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(23) "Map of extreme rainfall"
    ["url"]=>
    string(62) "http://dma.gdacs.org/saved/gdacs/tc/1000226/rain_1000226_2.png"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(34) "Map of extreme rainfall (original)"
    ["url"]=>
    string(97) "http://www.ssd.noaa.gov/PS/TROP/DATA/ETRAP/2015/NorthIndian/THREE/2015THREE.pmqpf.10100000.00.GIF"
  }

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Running through XML the regular path, is , from my experience, slow and excruciating.

Have a look into XPath -> it's a way to extract data from XML through selectors ( similar to CSS selectors )

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

You can select elements by their attributes similar to CSS

```
<?php
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('some_xml.xml'); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 

$items = $xml->xpath("//channel/item");

$urls_by_item = array();
foreach($items as $x) {
    $urls_by_item [] = $x->xpath("//gdacs:resources/gdacs:resource[@type='image']/@url");
}
```

Comment: this works, but the problem is that I get all the urls for all the items, I need to assign the particular urls to the particular items, if you look at the whole file, the XML contains many "items" nodes and I need to get for each "item", the URLs of resources of type "image". The solution you suggested generates an array of all xx type resources in the whole XML file regardless of which item they belong to

Comment: Make a SimpleXMLElement for each item separately, then run xpath on each of them in a loop. You can use 2 xpath statements -> first one fetches all items , the next one loops over the results using the code above